# Accessing files in subfolder AWS S3

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use an ajax request to get all image files in a subfolder of my s3 bucket.

I've made the subfolder public using the dropdown menu (see image), but am still getting a `403 (Forbidden)` response. I've also tried adding a bucket policy for that specific folder but still no luck.

Is there anything I should be doing permissions-wise that I'm missing? I would have thought making the subfolder public would have done the job.

Here's my call code if that helps:

```
var imgUrl = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/[BUCKET NAME]/images/gallery";
var loadedImages;
var imgData = {
        images: []
    }

$.ajax({
    url: imgUrl,
    success: function getData(data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function(i, val) {
            if (val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)) {

                loadedImages = $(this).attr("href"),
                    imgData.images.push($(loadedImages));
                    console.log(imgData)
            }
        });
    }
    });
```

**EDIT: Here's my bucket permission as it stands:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[BUCKET NAME]/*"
        },
        {
    "Sid":"PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::[BUCKET NAME]/images/gallery/*"
      ]
    }
    ]
}
```

[image: S3 subfolder permissions dropdown]

Comment: you might find this page interesting https://brandonwamboldt.ca/understanding-s3-permissions-1662/

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41251450/how-to-make-ajax-call-to-aws-s3-bucket-to-get-file-names-from-folder

Comment: Note that "make public" only applies to existing objects, not future objects.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Share your bucket Policy or if you need to provide *public read access* to bucket update policy like this :

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Sid":"PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/foldername/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Added my bucket policy to the original question